# Simulation of Experimental Design Data in R

Tags: r, simulation

I wonder how to simulate data for experimental designs, like Completely Randomized Design, Randomized Block Design, Latin Square design etc., in *R*. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything you're looking for can be found in [Experimental Design Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html).